# Disabling text grow animation for selected BottomNavigationBarItem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, flutter-animation

When I tap on BottomNavigationBarItem in my flutter app, I see animation - selected item's font size is increased.

Is there any way to disable it or control this behaviour?

Comment: check my answer you can disable BottomNavigationBarItem animation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes we can do this by setting **type** to **BottomNavigationBarType.fixed**

```
BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

Comment: this works for removing the width animation, but the font size still changes. it is now possible to set the font sizes, so I updated my answer

Answer (score 10):

```
selectedFontSize: fontSize,
unselectedFontSize: fontSize,
```

Answer (score -1):

**Updated answer** (2019-09):

You can now set the font size for the selected and unselected labels of [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html), so setting the same size will avoid the animation.

**Previous (accepted) answer** (2018-12):

I don't think this can be done without creating your own widget, since there's no option to disable the [font increasing animation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart#L257) present in Flutter's source.